# Mongoose - Make sure only the creator of object can delete it

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a Schema that among other fields has one that indicates the user that created it, called project_manager.

```
const mongoose        = require('mongoose');
const Schema          = mongoose.Schema;
const idValidator     = require('mongoose-id-validator');

(...)


let ProjetoSchema = new Schema({

  name  : {
    type     : String,
    required : true
  },

  goal  : {
    type     : String,
    required : true
  },

  activity :  {
    type      : AtividadeSchema,
    required  : true
  },

  date : {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },

  //  Teacher that initiates the activity
  project_manager : {
    type      : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref       : 'User',
    required  : true
  },

  //  Teachers invited to collaborate
  teachers : {
    type      : [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    ref       : 'User',
  }

});

ProjetoSchema.plugin(idValidator);


module.exports = mongoose.model('Projeto', ProjetoSchema);
```

I'm trying to make sure only the project_manager can delete a given Projeto, however I haven't been able to do that.

```
function remove(req, res) {

  let query = {
    _id : req.params.id
  };

  Projeto.findByIdAndRemove(query)
  .then(projeto =>  {

    if(!projeto) {   
      return res.status(404).json({error: 'not_found', message: 'This project doesn\'t exist.'});
    } 

    if(projeto.project_manager.toString() != req.user._id.toString()) {
      return res.status(403).json({error: 'forbidden', message: 'You can\'t delete this project.'});
    } 


    res.status(200).send("Project deleted.");


  })
  .catch(utils.handleError(req, res));
```

If I try deleting it with a different user the error message that the user isn't the project_manager is shown but the object is still deleted.

How can I ensure only the project_manager can delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `findByIdAndRemove` before validating ownership?

```
 function remove(req, res) {

  let query = {
    _id : req.params.id
  };

  Projeto.findById(query)
  .then(async (projeto) =>  {

    if(!projeto) {   
      return res.status(404).json({error: 'not_found', message: 'This project doesn\'t exist.'});
    } 

    if(projeto.project_manager.toString() != req.user._id.toString()) {
      return res.status(403).json({error: 'forbidden', message: 'You can\'t delete this project.'});
    } else {
      await Project.findByIdAndRemove(query);
    }


    res.status(200).send("Project deleted.");


  })
  .catch(utils.handleError(req, res));
```